# Why I don't see all items in Kentico Administration applications?

Tags: c#, kentico

I don't see all application in Kentico. Please help me.
Currently I am Global System Administrator. This is my new website.

Current situation with applications looks like this:

[image]

Can someone help me ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you need to check:

1. The user need to be set a Global Administrator in Users>User>General tab (dropdown list)
2. The user needs to be in the Global Administrator role which is part of the (global) roles.
3. You need to ensure any pre-configured roles which are assigned to the user for a particular site are removed. Reason being is any role with lower permissions will override any other "global" permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem when I created my first site. All license, user and domain were rightly setup. I even checked all the settings for pages module which looked right. The only noticeable thing was that the site was not showing on top ribon as shown in solution 3.

I just did a log off and log on which resolved the issue. :)

Thanks a lot Brenden for directing towards solution.

Answer (score -2):

I would first make sure the user you are using is set to Global Administrator, if not it would be permissions. If you can't access the users application, you can check in the database:

```
SELECT userid, username, dbo.CMS_User.UserIsGlobalAdministrator FROM  dbo.CMS_User  WHERE UserName  =USERNAME
```

If you are a global administrator, it's possible that something happened to the CMS_UIElement table.

Answer (score -2):

I have had a similar experience when working with a new site. Ensure that the appropriate site is selected (see image) and that the site has a valid license matching the Site domain name or alias (Sites -> {SiteName} -> General  ).  [image: Screengrab showing site selection]

Comment: If your instance doesn't have a valid license for that domain you won't even be able to get to the Pages application. Your answer won't fix anytihng the OP is having issues with.

Comment: @BrendenKehren I said that he should "ensure that there is a valid license for the site domain or alias"  and there is no mention of going to the Pages application. Still had the same issue this morning when changing a site domain name. I just went to licenses and added a license for the domain and went to Sites and added the domain as an alias.

Comment: So why the down vote to my answer @dipole?  I provided 3 valid solutions to the OP's issue.  My mention of accessing the Pages application is specifically related to your answer and the reason for my down vote to your answer.  The OP CAN get to the Pages application although cannot see any of the options in the menu.  If the license or domain alias was not valid, they wouldn't even be able to get to the Pages application.  It's specifically a permissions issue and not a license issue.

Comment: @BrendenKehren I didn't down vote your answer. I was just replying to your comment that my answer wouldn't fix anything.